# Is it possible to preserve plus signs in PHP $_GET vars without encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, get

Say I request this URL:

http://mydomain.com/script.php?var=2+2

$_GET['var'] will now be: "2 2" where it should be "2+2"

Obviously I could encode the data before sending and then decode it, but I'm wondering if this is the only solution. I could also replace spaces with plus symbols, but I want to allow spaces as well. I simply want whatever characters were passed, without any url decoding or encoding going on. Thank you!

Comment: You could just grab `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` - I think that gives you the raw text?

Comment: why wouldn't you url encode? The way to go IS to url encode so it will look like var=2%202 (where 20 is a number like that it will be the real number representing the sign +). And php has built in fonctions to decode!

Comment: The reason I didn't want to encode is, I wanted prettier URLs. On my website, URLs are in the in the URL. e.g. http://mydomain.com/url?url=http://google.com/ looks better than http://mydomain.com/url?url=http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2f (I tried http://mydomain.com/url/http://google.com/ but I could get that to work - it broke mod_rewrite and caused errors for some reason)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course. You could read out `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`, break it up yourself, and then forgo the usual URL decoding, or only convert `%xx` placeholders back.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)=([^&]+)/', $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $pairs);
$_GET = array_combine($pairs[1], $pairs[2]);
```

(Example only works for alphanumeric parameters, and doesn't do the mentioned %xx decoding. Just breaks up the raw input.)

Comment: Has no flag to prevent urldecoding on param values.

Comment: The data I need is in fact in $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], but parsing it is the issue. @webarto parse_str() converts the pluses to spaces

Comment: I found a hacked solution that worked using preg_match and $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] - thanks

Comment: This regex would not work for query strings like `foo-variable=foo-value&moo-variable=moo-value`, since `\w` excludes `-`.

Answer (score 8):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], "+") !== false){
    $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = str_replace("+", "%2B", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
    parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $_GET);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `urlencode`, though that would also translate any spaces to a plus. This makes sense, because a `+` in a URL usually represents a space. If you actually need a plus sign to mean a plus sign, you should probably escape the input. This means a `+` would become `%2B` and your URL would be `http://mydomain.com/script.php?var=2%2B2`.

Comment: That's what I meant by encoding it - I'm trying to find a prettier looking solution than all those % pound symbols and such so the links look for better when passing around.

Answer (score 1):

Whomever is generating the URL containing a `+` in the query segment is wrong unless they intend it to represent a space character.  A `+` in the query is a reserved character (re: [RFC2396 §3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.4)).  If you need to insert a literal `+` in the query string, then it must be encoded as `%2B` (re: [RFC2396 §2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.2)).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you can make the '+' symbol appear on a get request without the need submit the url with encoded symbols.

```
PHP Version 5.3.8
```

Submitting http://mydomain.com/script.php?var=2+2

Echo:

```
2+2
```

Using the following code:

```
<?php
echo urlencode($_GET['var']);
?>
```

Comment: That is actually wrong, since sending `2%202` will result the same instead of `2 2`

Answer (score 1):

A few steps required to do it.

- Just replace your query parameter plus (+) sign with '%2B' in the url
  before requesting the url.
- Now you will just retrieve the query    parameter. It will
  automatically replace '%2B' with plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `urlencode()` to - well - encode the URL and `urldecode($_Get())` to make the string usable again.